# angularjs factory data sharing

Tags: angularjs

I have written one factory to share data between controllers. Here is the sample

```
.factory('sharedData', function () {
        var property = {
            title: '',
            color: ''
        };

        return {
            getTitle: function () {
                return property.title;
            },
            setTitle: function (title) {
                property.title = title;
            },
            getColor: function () {
                return property.color;
            },
            setColor: function (color) {
                property.color = color;
            }
        };
```

I am using controller to set data in the factory using.

```
sharedData.setTitle("title");
```

but when I am trying to call:

```
console.log(sharedData.getTitle());
```

I am receiving empty string. I have injected service in both the controller properly. any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** 
Sorry to miss out one important information. I am setting the data after a successful REST call code is as below.

```
var req =
            {
                method: 'GET',
                url: "/titleName"
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                }

            };
            $http(req)
                .success(function (response, status)
                {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(response[0].name); 
                    sharedData.setTitle(response[0].name);
                    sharedData.setColor(response[1].color);

                })
                .error(function (response, status)
                {
                });
```

Json response is as below :

```
[{"name":"Name"},{"color":"red"}]
```

console.log in success callback is giving correct response as Name. Thanks

Comment: Likely some sort of asynchronous timing issue, would need to see more of usage code. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: might not be a reason, but you forgot comma `,` after `setTitle` in your example

Comment: no comma is not the issue that was a mistake from copy paste, i will edit the question

Comment: wouldn't have the problem if you shared reference to the actual object `property` and take advantage of prototypical inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//EDIT

Ah i see you use a an async method.
So yeah you should return the promise and resolve on success it.

Because the controller does't know if its async or not it just expects a value.

So while the service is retrieving the data the controller already asks for the data.

and then you will be returned an empty string.

When you return a promise you can resolve it in your routing or in your controller.

//Plunkr is old because data changed on the question
Hi i have created a really small plunkr.

```
.controller('har', function(sharedData) {
   sharedData.setTitle("test")
   console.log(sharedData.getTitle())
   sharedData.setTitle("test2")
   console.log(sharedData.getTitle())
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CvKgKtGmjCDxtk4dcbtv?p=preview

Check the console

I used your factory and a simple controller and for me it looks like it's working.

Do you have any other dependencies on it or do you use it differently.

Comment: yup that did it found another solution for working with promise in http get.